# Get roles of current user in Discord server

Tags: javascript, api, discord

I'm trying to get the roles of the current user in a specific chat room using Discord's API (using an access_token). I've had a fair look through the docs and can't see how to do this. For example, doing a get request to `https://discordapp.com/api/users/@me` gives the basic user info as expected. I then tried something along the lines of the following without any luck:

```
https://discordapp.com/api/users/@me/guilds/${guild.id}/roles
```

Here's a snippet of the code I'm using:

```
               ....get access token then

                .then(info => {
                    console.log(info)
                    fetch(`https://discordapp.com/api/users/@me`, {
                        headers: {
                            authorization: `${info.token_type} ${info.access_token}`,
                        },
                    }).then(response => response.json())
                        .then(info => {
                            console.log(info)
                        })
                })
```

Any ideas?

To clarify, the user logs in with discord and my application receives a user access token which I'm then trying to use to get the roles of the user in a specific discord room.

Answer (score 2):

There is

[GET /users/@me/guilds/{guild.id}/member](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#get-current-user-guild-member)

Which will get you [a JSON object containing](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#guild-member-object)

```
{
  "avatar": null,
  "communication_disabled_until": null,
  "flags": 0,
  "is_pending": null,
  "joined_at": "2023-01-11T23:12:34.423000+00:00",
  "nick": null,
  "pending": null,
  "premium_since": null,
  "roles": [
    2888141278217623600,
    5904405471246944000
  ],
  "user": {
    "id": 8285334657500223000,
    "username": "your-name",
    "display_name": null,
    "avatar": null,
    "avatar_decoration": null,
    "discriminator": 4041,
    "public_flags": 0
  },
  "mute": null,
  "deaf": null
}
```

To use this with OAuth2, you must request the [`guilds.members.read` OAuth2 scope](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#shared-resources-oauth2-scopes), which is the one that Discord prompts users for their permissions with

> Read your member info (nickname, avatar, roles, etc...) for servers you belong to

This was added in sometime in late 2021, judging from [this PR](https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/pull/4204).

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#get-guild-member) you can do this using the endpoint:

GET /guilds/{guild.id}/members/{user.id}

This will return a guild member object that contains the roles of this user.

Example guild member object:

```
{
  "user": {},
  "nick": "",
  "roles": [],
  "joined_at": "",
  "deaf": false,
  "mute": false
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks I tried this but got `{ message: '401: Unauthorized', code: 0 }`. I have the `guild` scope enabled when the user logs in with Discord

Comment: The documentation notes [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#privileged-intents) that to access certain things, including guild members,  "you must first go to your application in the Developer Portal and enable the toggle for the Privileged Intents you wish to use." Maybe that is your issue.

Comment: Does not work with access_token like OP asked. GET /guilds/{guild.id}/members/{user.id} is not a valid scope for oauth2.