# Discord API - Not allowed to request source

Tags: javascript, discord, fetch-api

I am trying to make „Login with Discord“ (OAuth) using Discords API. I need the users ID, the Name and the [role of the member in the guild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63234909/get-roles-of-current-user-in-discord-server).

It fails to fetch the source after I got redirected from the OAuth Page:

My JS for that page:

```
window.onload = () => {
  const fragment = new URLSearchParams(window.location.hash.slice(1));
  const [accessToken, tokenType] = [fragment.get('access_token'), fragment.get('token_type')];

  fetch('http://discord.com/api/guilds/874613987487121408/members/491553591434412057', {
    headers: {
      authorization: `${tokenType} ${accessToken}`,
    },
  })
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(response => {
      const username = response.user;
      const roles = response.roles;
      document.getElementById('info').innerText += username + roles;
    })
    .catch(console.error);
};
```

However, it gets me an error message:

> Not allowed to request source.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Try console logging your authorization header to make sure that it's a valid token output maybe.

Comment: Try changing it to: `${tokenType}=${accessToken}`

Comment: @dnorhoj Thank you so much!